# Compilation issue after updating the angular2 to angular4

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-aot

After updated version of angular4 from 2,  getting the below error on compile.

**Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function**

```
provideAuth({
    tokenName: 'token',
    tokenGetter: () => localStorage.getItem('token') 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the token fetch on a variable before assigning it, like so:

```
public function(): void {
    let token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');
    provideAuth({
        tokenName: 'token',
        tokenGetter: token
    });
}
```

Comment: Using in module file @NgModule({
    providers: [
        AUTH_PROVIDERS,
        provideAuth({
            tokenName: 'token',
            tokenGetter: () => localStorage.getItem('token') 
        })})

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're compiling with AOT compilation (which is a good thing, but has some limitations).

In this case, its because AOT does not support lambda functions in provider setup. See [the AOT documentation](https://angular.io/guide/metadata#no-arrow-functions). To fix it, just replace your lambda with a **named and exported** function:

```
export function getToken() { localStorage.getItem('token'); }
```

and then reference that instead:

```
provideAuth({
    tokenName: 'token',
    tokenGetter: getToken
})
```

There are quite a few other gotchas with AOT compilation, many of which are listed here: https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-writing-aot-friendly-applications-7b64c8afbe3f

You can of course alternatively opt to compile *without* AOT by omitting the `--aot` argument from your `ng build` command. But that will result in a larger, slower application.

Comment: Getting string can't be assigned to IAuthConfigOptional type error.

Comment: Sorry - should just be the method name. Updated.